# I don't have a Public folder in Dropbox

Tags: osx, dropbox

I don't see a 'public folder' in my list. I also don't get the option of creating a 'public link' from any file: All I can click is 'share link'. The links I'm getting only work when I'm logged in to my Dropbox account, and I'm guessing they only work for me.

How can I make a public link?

Comment: Won't the following work? `Right click --> Dropbox --> Share link`

Answer (score 9):

The *Public* folder was a feature in Dropbox that was later removed. It now exists only for users who've signed up before it was disabled.

For newer accounts, you can share a link to any file from any directory by clicking *Share Link*. You can't, however, get a direct public link from the context menu itself.

See: [What is the Public folder for? - Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/16/en)

> Please note: New Dropbox accounts created after October 4, 2012 no longer have a Public folder.

If you want your link to be public, you don't have to do anything special. In the web page that pops up once you click *Share Link*, make sure you click *Get Link* to get the public link. You could also copy the URL that's displayed in your browser (the one starting with `https://www.dropbox.com/s/some-random-string/filename`.

> [image]

Comment: I did this. But these links ONLY work when I'm logged into my own dropbox account. If I'm not logged in, I get error 403. I need the link to work whether or not I'm logged in, for everybody.

Comment: That can't be – just click *Share Link* in the context menu, then *Get link* on the website or copy the URL. See: [How do I link to a file or folder?](https://www.dropbox.com/help/167/en)

Comment: ok -- I got it to work. One more problem: My pdf that opens from the link has a white border on the left. Why is that? It's not in the file. Only in the file that opens from the link.

Comment: It's probably because the share link embeds a frame around the file. Can you try exchanging the `www.dropbox.com` to `dl.dropbox.com` in the shared link?

Comment: that worked. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 3):

Dropbox links described by slhck give you everything you need to share and preview files and folders. However, if you want to use the old system of Public Folders, click below to enable one on your account.

https://www.dropbox.com/enable_public_folder

Source: https://www.dropbox.com/help/16/en